# How to repair a piano that was damaged during a move?

Tags: wood, veneer

We hired professional movers to transport a grand piano across a few states.  However, the movers damaged it (with a forklift?).  What is a good way to repair the damage, where the gouge is quite deep and wide?

[image]

Comment: Hmm. Piano Movers, or just movers? There's often an unfortunate difference.

Comment: We hired movers who supposedly move pianos for piano dealers.  It probably changed "hands" a few times during the trip as it moved from the West Coast to the East Coast.

Comment: Do you have any home contents insurance with a lower deductible? (Not sure if they'd pay, but worth asking.) BTW, my sympathies. It's no fun having something like this happen.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask for the cost of hiring the professional to repair the damaged area. I've also had my U3 Yamaha damaged during a moving house. Both sides at the bottom wooden frame were badly scratched when these movers lifted it up stairs

Comment: Tony: it cost $600.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the purported professionals were actually insured, you find the local piano shop (if one currently in production, ideally the shop dealing in that brand) and inquire about having it fixed, on the movers (or the movers' insurance's) dime. If it needs to move to get fixed, use Piano Movers.

Comment: Yes we bought insurance but the deductible is probably too high (over $1k) to be useful.  It's a Yamaha, but we contacted a professional repair person who works on Steinways.

Answer (score 1):

The finish will be almost impossible to match entirely, but if the damage is just skin deep (like a horridly bad scratch) and didn't hurt the structure or internals, you could remove anything proud of the surface . Fill the gouge with filler then sand, prime and paint.  It would look better from afar, but you'd still see it in person from a few feet away.  Even a professional repair may be noticeable from close up, depending on the skill of the craftsman.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up hiring a professional repair person who works for Steinway to make the repair.  He used a polyester filler.  The results are very good but not perfect.  I will post a picture soon.